# is there a specific way to implement card elements from stripe in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement stripe in my vue js project and i dont know why my script is not working .

I created a payement.vue page so i can put the stripe element form and on my assets/js i put the js they gave us with that form (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart). I tried to link the js file to my payment.vue and to link the script stire gave us but that gave me error like "stripe is not deffined". I also trie to put the two script on my index.html on the  but that gave me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined". And also i tried to put the script that stipe gave us on my assets/js/stipe but it didnt not work can someone help me here?

````
first attempt on my payement.vue

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
import Stripe from '@/assets/js/stripe'

export default {

}
</script>

<------------------------------------------------------------------>
second attempt on my assets/js/stripe

 <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6AGwTFQ4NxLa3P3VmPnT8ZJ8');
const elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  const card = elements.create('card', {style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', ({error}) => {
    const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (error) {
      displayError.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const {token, error} = await stripe.createToken(card);

  if (error) {
    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
    const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server.
    stripeTokenHandler(token);
  }
});

const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }; ```

i'm just trying to find the best way to implement the form strip element and where to put the js and the (<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
) they gave us , ty for your answer.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually do it is to load stripe in the footer or header of my site or application template outside of the vue app element.

```
<!--- beginning of vue app container -->
<div id="app"> 
   <v-content>
      //...
   </v-content> 
</div>
<!--- end app container -->

<script src="{{url('/js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

This is the recomendation of Stripe for better security.

> To best leverage Stripe’s advanced fraud functionality, include this script on every page of your site, not just the checkout page. This allows Stripe to detect anomalous behavior that may be indicative of fraud as customers browse your website.

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs

If you still want or need to include the script directly in your component, you should be able to do it as follows in your components `mounted()` function.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () {
       return {
          //...
       }
    },
    mounted() {
       let stripeJs = document.createElement('script');
       stripeJs.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/');
       document.head.appendChild(stripeJs);
    },
  }
</script>
```